# Getting the sum of a column's cells from visible rows in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sum

I have a data grid view in which I can invisible or hide some rows and in this process I should get the sum of the 6th column cells (only from visible rows) the code I've written inside a context menu item click event gives me an exception says: "Input string was not in a correct format." in this line of code:

```
count += Convert.ToInt32(addSellItemsDgv.Rows[row.Index].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
```

My code for the context menu item click event:

```
private void toolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in addSellItemsDgv.SelectedRows)
    {
        CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[addSellItemsDgv.DataSource];
        currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();
        addSellItemsDgv.CurrentCell = null;
        row.Visible = false;
    }
    addSellItemsDgv.Refresh();
    int count = 0;
    if (addSellItemsDgv.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in addSellItemsDgv.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Visible == true)
            {
                count += Convert.ToInt32(addSellItemsDgv.Rows[row.Index].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        addSellTtlCostLbl.Text = count.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        addSellTtlCostLbl.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: You maybe have a blank row. Check the `Cell.Value` for 'null' before you attempt to convert the value to `int32`.

Comment: @peeebeee it has a value , all cells have values

Comment: Run in the debugger and inspect the value you're trying to convert when you get the exception, then.

Comment: You can't bind data to the datagrid unless you have the data first. Why not calculate the values you need from the data used to populate the datagrid, instead of populating the datagrid and then trying to read from that?

Answer (score 0):

Altough we are missing some more context here, I guess that either `Convert.ToInt32` receives an alphanumeric value, or a value that would exceed Int32. Please double check the string value that you are passing to `Convert.ToInt32` and also try to `Trim` the string beforehand.

Also, I would recommend to use `Int32.TryParse`. This will help you to prevent this exception and validate the user input.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by converting ToDouble instead of ToInt32 and using the row object instead of Rows[row.Index] :)

```
private void toolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in addSellItemsDgv.SelectedRows)
    {
        CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[addSellItemsDgv.DataSource];
        currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();
        addSellItemsDgv.CurrentCell = null;
        row.Visible = false;
    }
    addSellItemsDgv.Refresh();
    double count = 0;
    if (addSellItemsDgv.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in addSellItemsDgv.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Visible == true)
            {
                count += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[6].FormattedValue.ToString());
            }
        }
        addSellTtlCostLbl.Text = count.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        addSellTtlCostLbl.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you've solved it. It would still be good practice to check for invalid numbers before hitting a 'Convert' - `TryParse` is a good mechanism.

Comment: @peeebeee I will keep this in my mind for further practice :)